# How to do conditional formatting on individual rows in same column?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I want to do conditional formatting on the following data.

[Data Image](https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-f.ak/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t1.0-0/10455371_1527000860854592_6334861694092594037_a.jpg)

When first column (1c) value is equal to second(2c). Paint green else paint red.

Compare:

```
     1r1c to 1r2c

     2r1c to 2r2c

     3r1c to 3r2c
```

Currently it is comparing r1c1, r2c1 and r3c1 to r1c2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your current conditional formatting rule?

edit:
OK, your current rules are `=$E$2` and `<>$E$2`, both applies to `=$D$2`
You are telling MS Excel to compare cell D2 with cell E2. First you have to apply your rules over area `D2:D_many` (you can apply rule over both columns to get both cells colored, sometimes it's useful). Second remove `$` in your rules, change rules to `=E2` or `=$E2` If you apply conditional formatting rule over one column (D), there will be no difference, but if you apply rule over multiple columns (for example D:H), first one will compare cell with cell in the same row but one column right, second one will compare cell with cell in the same row and column E.

Comment: Current rules are:
https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/scontent-b.xx/hphotos-xpa1/t1.0-9/10502220_1527049284183083_2948321785450704769_n.jpg

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I am trying to create a rule for comparing column D to column E but each row should get compared individually. Means D1 should get compared to E1 and D2 should get compared to E2. When I am trying to compare the values of D1:D_many to E1:E_many it is not allowing me to create the rule. as it is not comparing multiple to multiple values, but multiple to one only i.e. D1:D_many to E1 only.
Data I am using is [here](https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-b.ak/hphotos-ak-xap1/t1.0-0/10450819_1527229984165013_2704075400602919506_a.jpg)

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you to figure out the rules! It would be nice to have first accepted answer too!

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

I tried to create a new rule and got the correct format. I used [this](https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/sphotos-g.ak/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10455440_1527247577496587_5726409017376633236_n.jpg?oh=b434be53ca753c1c37087c3b7cb5c784&oe=541A359E&__gda__=1411349671_cb9a441ba0fcfba6976283ed59e070cd) formula.

And the rule created was [this](https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/scontent-a.xx/hphotos-xfa1/t1.0-9/10426607_1527247110829967_8579815838448954659_n.jpg)

Now working fine. Thanks.